# upload image file in laravel is not working

Tags: laravel

i'm doing upload image file by laravel and that image is not to update to database. It's my controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $imageName = "test-" . uniqid() . "." . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file('image')->move(base_path() . '/public/media/', $imageName);
        $model->image = url('/media/' . $imageName);
    }
```

and thí is my view

```
    <input id="image" class="hidden" name="image" type="file"/>
          <img src="" alt="" id="preview-img">
           <div class="center upload-img">
              <label for="image">
                  <u>Upload</u>
             </label>
           </div>
```

anyone help me solve that. thanks!

Comment: form html tag is multipart?

Comment: ohhh thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a **MultiPart** form

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```